# Task counter C#, Interlocked

Tags: c#, task

I would like to run tasks in parallel, with no more than 10 instances running at a given time.

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void Listen()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var context = listener.GetContext();
        var task = Task.Run(() => HandleContextAsync(context));
        Interlocked.Increment(ref countTask);
        if (countTask > 10)
        {
            //I save tasks in the collection
        }
        else
        {
            task.ContinueWith(delegate { Interlocked.Decrement(ref countTask); }); //I accomplish the task and reduce the counter
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question: is my code correct?  If so then it depends what you want it to do.

Comment: @pm_2 Yes, my question: is my code correct? I want to limit the number of tasks using the task counter. Once the number of tasks has reached the limit, I put them in the queue. So I want to implement throttling with the task counter and queue.

Comment: So you want to start a defined number of tasks (in this case - 10)?

Comment: @pm_2 Yes true.

Comment: @mjwills The `countTask` is a thread-safe counter that limits the number of tasks

Comment: @mjwills In `if` I put the task in the queue and wait until 10 tasks are processed

Comment: @mjwills And how can I still limit the number of tasks?My server must withstand the load exceeding its capabilities. I'm trying to solve this problem this way

Comment: Did my solution work for you @MartyMcFly ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a Parallel loop; for example:

```
Parallel.For(1, 10, a =>
{
      var context = listener.GetContext();
      ...
});
```

That will start a defined number of tasks without you needing to manage the process yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continually execute code in parallel, with up to 10 instances at a time, this may be worth considering:

```
private void Listen()
{
    var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };
    Parallel.For(1, long.MaxValue - 1, options, (i) =>
    {
        var context = listener.GetContext();
        HandleContextAsync(context);
    });
}
```

Basically, it will run the code continually (well roughly `long.MaxValue` times). `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` ensures that it runs only 10 'instances' of the code at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the result from `GetContext` is not created by you, so, its probably not useful to use a `Parallel.For` when you don't know how many times to run or don't have all the contexts to handle right away.

So, probably the best way to resolve this would be by implementing your own `TaskScheduler`. This way you can add more tasks to be resolved on demand with a fixed concurrency level.

Based on the example from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8#examples) website you can already achieve this.

I made an example program with some changes to the `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` from the website.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace parallel
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Random Rand = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(10);
            var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(ts);

            while (true)
            {
                var context = GetContext(ts);
                if (context.Equals("Q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    break;
                taskFactory.StartNew(() => HandleContextAsync(context));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");

            while (ts.CountRunning != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Now running {0}x tasks with {1}x queued.", ts.CountRunning, ts.CountQueued);
                Thread.Yield();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        private static void HandleContextAsync(string context)
        {
            // delays for 1-10 seconds to make the example easier to understand
            Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next(1000, 10000));

            Console.WriteLine("Context: {0}, from thread: {1}", context, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        private static string GetContext(LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler ts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Now running {0}x tasks with {1}x queued.", ts.CountRunning, ts.CountQueued);
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    // Provides a task scheduler that ensures a maximum concurrency level while 
    // running on top of the thread pool.
    public class LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
    {
        // Indicates whether the current thread is processing work items.
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static bool _currentThreadIsProcessingItems;

        // The list of tasks to be executed 
        private readonly LinkedList<Task> _tasks = new LinkedList<Task>(); // protected by lock(_tasks)

        public int CountRunning => _nowRunning;

        public int CountQueued
        {
            get
            {
                lock (_tasks)
                {
                    return _tasks.Count;
                }
            }
        }

        // The maximum concurrency level allowed by this scheduler. 
        private readonly int _maxDegreeOfParallelism;

        // Indicates whether the scheduler is currently processing work items. 
        private volatile int _delegatesQueuedOrRunning = 0;
        private volatile int _nowRunning;

        // Creates a new instance with the specified degree of parallelism. 
        public LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
        {
            if (maxDegreeOfParallelism < 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxDegreeOfParallelism");
            _maxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
        }

        // Queues a task to the scheduler. 
        protected sealed override void QueueTask(Task task)
        {
            // Add the task to the list of tasks to be processed.  If there aren't enough 
            // delegates currently queued or running to process tasks, schedule another. 
            lock (_tasks)
            {
                _tasks.AddLast(task);
                if (_delegatesQueuedOrRunning < _maxDegreeOfParallelism)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _delegatesQueuedOrRunning);
                    NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork();
                }
            }
        }

        // Inform the ThreadPool that there's work to be executed for this scheduler. 
        private void NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork()
        {
            ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
            {
                // Note that the current thread is now processing work items.
                // This is necessary to enable inlining of tasks into this thread.
                _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = true;
                try
                {
                    // Process all available items in the queue.
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Task item;
                        lock (_tasks)
                        {
                            // When there are no more items to be processed,
                            // note that we're done processing, and get out.
                            if (_tasks.Count == 0)
                            {
                                Interlocked.Decrement(ref _delegatesQueuedOrRunning);
                                break;
                            }

                            // Get the next item from the queue
                            item = _tasks.First.Value;
                            _tasks.RemoveFirst();
                        }

                        // Execute the task we pulled out of the queue
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref _nowRunning);
                        if (base.TryExecuteTask(item))
                            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _nowRunning);
                    }
                }
                // We're done processing items on the current thread
                finally { _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = false; }
            }, null);
        }

        // Attempts to execute the specified task on the current thread. 
        protected sealed override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
        {
            // If this thread isn't already processing a task, we don't support inlining
            if (!_currentThreadIsProcessingItems) return false;

            // If the task was previously queued, remove it from the queue
            if (taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
                // Try to run the task. 
                if (TryDequeue(task))
                    return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
                else
                    return false;
            else
                return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
        }

        // Attempt to remove a previously scheduled task from the scheduler. 
        protected sealed override bool TryDequeue(Task task)
        {
            lock (_tasks) return _tasks.Remove(task);
        }

        // Gets the maximum concurrency level supported by this scheduler. 
        public sealed override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel { get { return _maxDegreeOfParallelism; } }

        // Gets an enumerable of the tasks currently scheduled on this scheduler. 
        protected sealed override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
        {
            bool lockTaken = false;
            try
            {
                Monitor.TryEnter(_tasks, ref lockTaken);
                if (lockTaken) return _tasks;
                else throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(_tasks);
            }
        }
    }
}
```